# A version of Newton Raphson (Newton's method)

Tags: java, sqrt, newtons-method

```
public class Sqrt
  {
     public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           double EPS = 1E-15;
           double c = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
           double t = c;
              while (Math.abs(t - c/t) > t * EPS)
                      { t = (c/t + t) / 2.0; }
              System.out.println(t);
          }
      }
```

Above is one version of Newton Raphson i found in Java.
I suppose it works but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how it actually works. `{ t = (c/t + t) / 2.0; }` really confuses me.

I'm familiar with `x_n+1 = x_n - f(x_n)/ f'(x_n)` but not the one implemented in the code above..

Comment: What is your function f(x_n) ?

Comment: I think it's a rewrite of `(c+t^2) / (2.0 * t)`, if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to apply the Newton-Raphson-method you have to find a function, for which the zero is the solution you are looking for. In the case of square-root this is:

```
f(x) = x^2 - c
```

Now if you find a `x` with `f(x) = 0` you have found a square root of c.

```
f'(x) = 2*x
```

so

```
x - f(x)/f'(x) = x - ( (x^2 - c) / (2*x) ) = 1/2 * (x + c/x)
```

which is where your `(c/t + t) / 2.0` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Let `t = sqrt(c)`

```
=> t^2 = c   
=> 2t^2 - t^2 = c   
=> 2t^2 = t^2 + c
```

Let divide both side by `2t` we get

```
=> t = (t^2 + c)/2t   
=> t = (t + c/t)/2   
=> t = (c/t + t)/2
```

Comment: This only shows that the solution is a fixed point of the recursive equation